# Pandas Python user input an attribute for dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to allow the user to input the attribute for the dataframe object.

I've tried changing my input into a string. I've also tried using my input saved to a variable. Both these options do not work.

```
data = pd.read_csv('2019FallEnrollees.csv')

input1_col = input("Enter comparison group A: ")
input2_col = input("Enter comparison group B: ")

input1_str= str(input1_col)
input2_str = str(input2_col)

test = data[['CUM_GPA', input1_str, input2_str]]

# error here! 'test' does not have attribute 'input1_str' or 'input1_col'
df_1 = test[(test.input1_str == 0) & (test.input2_str == 0)]
df_2 = test[(test.input1_col == 1) & (test.input2_col == 0)]

print(stats.ttest_ind(df_1.CUM_GPA, df_2.CUM_GPA, equal_var = False))
```

The error messages says

"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'input1_str'
or 
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'input1_col'

Comment: You cannot use the `.` notation to access column names through variables. These need to be changed to `test[input1_str]`

Comment: There is no sense in casting input to string, hence input() function returns a string. In other words, str(input1_col) is the same as input1_col.

Comment: To add to @ALollz, best practice is to _always_ use the bracket `df['col']` notation to access dataframe columns, rather than the dot `df.col` notation for this, and many other reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!
To access a column in pandas you cannot use `data.column`
Try `data[column]` or in your case `test[input1_col]`
Before you do so, make sure the column does exist and the user is not inputting a nonexistant column.

Sometimes the column name can be an integer and converting to a string may also be a concern

You can get a list of all the dataframe columns through running `data.columns` (if you want a regular array: `list(data.columns)`) and infact you can alter the column names through running `data.columns = ["Column Header 1" , "Column Header 2" etc.]`